# How to skip_callback before_save for specific user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-activerecord

I've a method named `update` inside my `DailyOrdersController`:

```
def update
    if @daily_order.update( daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}) )
        respond_or_redirect(@daily_order)
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

My `DailyOrder` model:

```
before_save :refresh_total

def refresh_total
    # i do something here
end
```

What I'm trying to do now is, I want the `refresh_total` callback to be skipped if the update request is coming from `current_admin`.

I have 2 user model generated using Devise gem:

1. User (has `current_user`)
2. Admin (has `current_admin`)

I try to make it like this:

```
def update
   if current_admin
      DailyOrder.skip_callback :update, :before, :refresh_total
   end

   if @daily_order.update( daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}) )
      respond_or_redirect(@daily_order)
   else
      render :edit
   end
end
```

But it's not working and still keep calling the `refresh_total` callback if the update request is coming from `current_admin` (when the logged-in user is admin user).

What should I do now?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is all what you need:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

If you skip callback, you should enable it later. Anyway, this does not look as the best solution. Perhaps you could avoid the callbacks otherwise.

One way would be to use update_all:

```
DailyOrder.where(id: @daily_order.id).update_all( daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}) )
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
#in the model:
before_validation :refresh_total

#in the controller
@daily_order.assign_attributes( daily_order_params.merge({default_order:false}) )
@daily_order.save(validate: current_admin.nil?)
```

or maybe it would be the best to add a new column to the model: **refresh_needed** and then you would conditionally update that column on before_validation, and on before_save you would still call the same callback, but conditionally to the state of refresh_needed. In this callback you should reset that column. Please let me know if you would like me to illustrate this with some code.

---

This may come in handy: 
http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

---

**UPDATE**

Even better, you can call *update_columns*.
Here is what it says in the [documentation of the method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L304):

> Updates the attributes directly in the database issuing an UPDATE SQL
>     statement and sets them in the receiver:
>
> user.update_columns(last_request_at: Time.current)
>
> This is the fastest way to update attributes because it goes straight to
>     the database, but take into account that in consequence the regular update
>     procedures are totally bypassed. In particular:
>
> - \Validations are skipped.
> - \Callbacks are skipped.
> - +updated_at+/+updated_on+ are not updated.
>
>   This method raises an ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError when called on new
>     objects, or when at least one of the attributes is marked as readonly.